# How can I make AutocompleteInput or SelectArrayInput scrollable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, admin-on-rest

I'm using the `AutocompleteInput` and `SelectArrayInput` from `AOR` framework and want to select from lots of items. Unfortunately, the menu doesn't fit properly on the screen.

How can I make the list scrollable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Material UI documentation you can pass `listStyle` properties through options:

```
<ReferenceArrayInput label="Parts" source="partId" reference="parts" allowEmpty>
    <AutocompleteInput optionText="name"
       options={{ listStyle: { overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: 200}}} />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

Depending on your implementation you could also have the same behavior with `SelectManyInput`:

```
<ReferenceArrayInput label="Parts" source="partId" reference="parts" allowEmpty>
    <SelectManyInput optionText="name"
       options={{ listStyle: { overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: 200}}} />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

Material UI doc: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete
Rest Admin doc: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#autocompleteinput

Something like that:

[image]